# Correct way to model foreign keys to entities that do not (yet) exist?

Tags: spring-boot, database-design, spring-data-jpa

I'm building a Spring Boot application using Spring Data JPA. I'll give a simplified description of the application that illustrates my problem:

I have a table of Students that has a student_id primary key and various personal information (incl name, etc). This personal data is loaded from an external source and may only be retrieved once the student gives his permission to retrieve it by logging into the application. I thus cannot create a list of all the users that might log in ahead of time. They are created and inserted into the database when the student logs in the first time.

I also load data sets like historical grades into the database ahead of time. These are of the form student_id (foreign key), course_id (foreign key), grades, year (and some other fields). The point is that once a student logs in, their historical grades will be visible. However, the database (initialized as empty by Spring Data JPA) will not let me insert the historical data as it complains that e.g. student_id 1234 (foreign key in the grades table) cannot be found as a primary key in the Students table. Which is true, because I will only create that user 1234 when and if he/she logs in.

I see the following options and don't really like any of them:

1. disable all constraints on foreign keys for the relevant classes (in which case: How do I tell Spring Data JPA to do that? I googled but couldn't find it) -> Disabling integrity checks sounds like a bad idea though.
2. Create 'dummy' students, i.e. simply go through the historical data, list all the student_id's and then pre-fill my Student table with entries like student_id = 1234, name = "", address = "", etc. This data would be filled in if/when the students logs in -> This also feels like a 'dirty' solution.
3. Keep the historical data in .csv files, or another manually created table and have the application load it into the 'real' database only after the student logs in for the first time -> This just sounds like a terrible mess.

Conceptually I'm inclined towards option 1, because I do in fact want to create/save a piece of historical data about a student, despite having no other information about that student. I'm afraid, however, that if I e.g. retrieve all grades for a course_id, those Grade entities will contain links to Student entities that do not in fact exist and this will just result in more errors.

How do you handle such a situation?

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand you correctly. If a student logs in, populate the student table and after that the historical grades. The student can view them anyway only if he/she is logged in ("The point is that once a student logs in, their historical grades will be visible."). Then why would you need to insert this data in the database AOT?

Comment: The data is delivered to me in the form of excel sheets (one sheet contains the data of many hundreds of students). It's not like I can load it from an API or so. 
If I want to automatically load the grades after a student logs in for the first time, then where is it stored in the meantime? If in another database this only moves the problem to that database and requires two databases. Splitting into a file per student and reading those into the database when the student logs in is slow and feels clunky.